# How to pass a function to another state in functional components in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project. In that project I am showing data in a table, which is coming from backend. In that table I am showing Min and Max values coming from backend.

Under table I have two buttons, first button is Change to Min, second button is Change to Max.

Now what I am trying to do is, I am trying to do sorting to Max value. My goal is if I click the "Change to Min" button then in UI all the Max values has to show values in Ascending order to descending order. Now if I click the button Change to Max then in UI all the Max values has to show values in descending order to ascending order.

I have written sorting functions also and I applied that function to Change to Min button. But from that I don't know how to pass that function to another state.

This is list.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import Aumservice from '../../service/aum-service';
import { MdEdit } from 'react-icons/md';
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";


const List = (props) => {

const [sortData, setSortData] = useState(null)

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
        (async function () {
            const response = await Aumservice.getAum()
            const dataResponse = response.data.list.map(ele => ele.maxValue)
            setSortData(dataResponse)
            setData(response.data.list)
        })()
    }, [])

const sortAscending = () => {
        let sortedData = sortData.sort((a, b) => a - b)
        console.log(sortedData)
        setData(sortedData)
    }
    const sortDescending = () => {
        let sortedData = sortData.sort((a, b) => b - a)
        setData(sortedData)
    }

return (
        <div>
<IconContext.Provider
                value={{ size: '25px' }}
            >
                <Table bordered>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>So No</th>
                            <th>Min</th>
                            <th>Max</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {data.map((currentValue, index) => {
                            return < tr key={index + 1} >
                                <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                                <td>{currentValue.minValue}</td>
                                <td>{currentValue.maxValue}</td>
                               </tr>
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </IconContext.Provider>
            <div className='min pr-5'>
                <Button onClick={sortAscending} className='primary'>Change to Min</Button>
            </div>
            <div className='max'>
                <Button className='secondary'>Change to Max</Button>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default List
```

Comment: you are displaying data in your table however you change the state of sortData which is not rendered. you could , in your sorting function to setData instead of setSortData

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have update the code. Please check it. hope it helps you.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Table, Button} from 'reactstrap';
import {IconContext} from "react-icons";

const SortedDataExample = (props) => {
    const [sortData, setSortData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSortData([23, 435, 23, 345, 76, 878]);
    }, []);

    const sortAscending = () => {
        let sortedData = sortData.sort((a, b) => a - b);
        console.log(sortedData);
        setSortData(sortedData);
    };
    const sortDescending = () => {
        let sortedData = sortData.sort((a, b) => b - a);
        console.log(sortedData);
        setSortData(sortedData);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <IconContext.Provider
                value={{size: '25px'}}
            >
                <Table bordered>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>So No</th>
                        <th>Min</th>
                        <th>Max</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {sortData.map((currentValue, index) => {
                        return < tr key={index + 1}>
                            <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                            <td>{currentValue.minValue}</td>
                            <td>{currentValue.maxValue}</td>
                        </tr>
                    })}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </IconContext.Provider>
            <div className='min pr-5'>
                <Button onClick={sortAscending} className='primary'>Change to Min</Button>
            </div>
            <div className='max'>
                <Button onClick={sortDescending} className='secondary'>Change to Max</Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default SortedDataExample
```